# How do i get the return value from command prompt in NSIS installer?

Tags: command-line, scripting, installation, command-prompt, nsis

I am trying to get the password which i entered in the command prompt while generating key store in the NSIS installer script.

How do i get the password from command prompt in a variable??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are going to need some more information because I have no idea what you are talking about. A command executed in the command prompt can only return a number. The only place to store a string would be in a environment variable but that is not a good place to store a password and the parent process will not have access to it anyway. Can you pipe it to a file in %temp%?

Comment: @Anders thank for reply. I made a dialog box to create keystore and provide input text. After user enter all details, i get the details from text boxes and execute the command with Execwait. The command doesn't contain password so command prompt ask for password and i want to get that password into a variable. So can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ExecDos plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in) can provide stdin text to the command you are executing.